# How do I generate a list of all items in a sprint that are blocked and the reason recorded for why they were blocked?

Tags: rally

I've tried doing this with version 1.3n of the SDK but cannot get the BlockedReason. There is a StackOverflow that points me to version 2.0rc1 of the SDK but I've not been able to work out how to retrieve more than one data type and put them all into a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlockedReason was introduced in version 1.38 of WS API, which is beyond the latest version of AppSDK 1.33.
There is a way to specify a WS API version beyond that point by using

```
rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
```

while the javascript src points to 1.33:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js"></script>
```

Here is a full example:

```
function tableExample() {
   var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('1111','2222','false','false'); //use valid workspace project OIDs if running outside of Rally
   rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
  function itemQuery() {
     var queryObject = {
       key: "t",
       type: "task",
       fetch: "FormattedID,Name,State,Blocked,BlockedReason",
   query: "(State = In-Progress)"
     };
     rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
  }

  function populateTable(results) {
     var rankIx = 1;
        for (var i=0; i < results.t.length; i++, rankIx++) {
            results.t[i].Ranking = rankIx;  
        }
     var tableDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');
     var config = { columns:
         [{key: 'Ranking', header: '#', width: 20},
     {key: 'FormattedID', header: 'Formatted ID', width: 100},
     {key: 'Name'},
     {key: 'BlockedReason', header: 'Blocked Reason', width: 200},
         {key: 'State'}]};

    var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
     table.addRows(results.t);
     table.display(tableDiv);

  };
  itemQuery();
 }

 rally.addOnLoad(tableExample);
```

Comment: Thanks for that I can now see the Blocked Reason.

Comment: You can also specify it in the script include:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.38